# Lebesgue sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Can anyone tell me strictly what Lebesgue sigma algebra is? Is it sigma algebra $m=\left\{ E \subset X | (\forall A \subset X) \mu ^{*} (A) = \mu ^{*} (A \cap E) + \mu ^{*} (A \cup E^c) \right\}$ on $X$, where $X$ is a set and $\mu ^{*}$ is the outer measure, from Caratheorody's theorem? Thank you, I am new to this

Comment: Yes it is going to be the sigma algebra of the sets that satisfy that. If u want u can try to prove it is in fact a sigma algebra.

Answer (score 2):

"Yes" under the extra conditions that $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu^*$ denotes the [outer Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Definition) (which is usually denoted as $\lambda^*$).

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent definition is the sets $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a Borel set $B$ and a Borel set $N$ such that $\mu(N) = 0$ ($\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure) such that $S \triangle B \subseteq N$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference, *i.e.* $S \triangle B = (S \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus S)$.